# How can I implement something like "If the player presses both ctrl and w" the moving speed (forwardforce) will be 2000 instead of like 1000

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am fairly new to c#, like 2 days new and I don't know how I can implement this feature, I am currently trying out something and I want to know how can I make it so that if the player presses both ctrl and w keys his speed (aka forward force for me) will go up to be like a thousand. (p.s it is in unity3d

here is what i wrote

which i am fairly sure is wrong so would appreciate if something helps me :D

I havent tried much honestly am still fairly fairly new

```
 // Super speed

    if (Input.GetKey("KeyCode.Control & w "))
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, 1000 * Time.deltaTime);             
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to have like 2 different speeds, then

```cs
void Update()
{
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) // Check if key W is pressed
  {
    var force = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftCtrl) ? 1000 : 500; // Check if key left ctrl is ALSO pressed. If it is the force is 1000, else the force is 500
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, force * Time.deltaTime);
  }
}
```